# can I use Ant to record the release history?

Tags: java, ant, build

Right now I have a **version.properties** file and **ant** can update its content automatically when I do release (a java application). The content of that version file is this:

```
buildDate=01-03-2012 165937
buildNum=1
buildMinor=0
buildMajor=0
```

Now I want to maintain the release history into a file (a new file probably, saying **history.properties**) in case I want to know which release was released at when.

In order to do this, I have to make **ant** to do the following for me automatically:

1. **read the existing information** from the **version.properties** file and joint them into one string, for example a string like this: **0.0.1 01-03-2012 165937** ;
2. **insert or append** the new string into the **history.properties** file;

Can anybody tell me does ant can do above 1 and 2 or not? if yes, how?

Or share with me your better solution.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this target to store versions log in the end of each build:
`<target name="save_version_history">
  <property file="version.properties" />
  <echo file="history.log" append="true" >${buildMajor}.${buildMinor}.${buildNum} ${buildDate}
</echo>
</target>`

Comment: I like your way. But I have to use "loadproperties", the "property" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you mind telling why? I'm just curious in what way loadproperties works better for you.

Comment: one more thing, the result is in one long line when opened with notepad but in different lines when opened with other editor. is there a way to write to the file always show different lines?

Comment: if not use loadproperties, the information in the version.properties file will not available. I noticed this when I tried my solution.

Comment: If by notepad you mean windows notepad than you need to use CRLF as end-of-the-line. It would seem that just LF was used instead. If you have notepad++ you can use it to check this out. Try using ${line.separator} instead of new line I used in the echo.

Comment: Just tested it: a blank line within echo leads to LF while ${line.separator} leads to CRLF on Windows system (probably system end-of-the-line symbol is used).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution now. I changed the format of the history.properties to

```
version=date
```

for example:

**0.0.1=01-03-2012 165937**

Then I use the following ant target for this:

```
<target name="history" depends="init" >
        <loadproperties srcFile="${version.file}"/>
        <propertyfile
            file="${history.file}" comment="Build history info">
            <entry key="${buildMajor}.${buildMinor}.${buildNum}" type="string" value="${buildDate}"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
```

because the entry key is different each time, so **ant** will **append** to the end of the history.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative solution, why not try the [JReleaseInfo ANT task](http://jreleaseinfo.sourceforge.net/ant_e.html)?

It works by generating a Java class file containing the specified release information. This class can be interrogated at run-time by other parts of your code. There is even an option to support a graphical runtime viewer.